# Can I omit "the" in this sentence?

Tags: definite-article, ellipsis

> Dan has already given you a sense of the dramatic change that occurred between **the** '20s and **the** '30s.

Can I omit the second highlighted **the** in this sentence? I know there is a thing called *ellipsis*, that allows you instead of writing `the A and the B` just write `the A and B.`

Comment: Yes, you may. To be persnickety, however, nothing occurred *between* the 20s and the 30s: there was no time between them, the transition was instantaneous. What you probably mean is either the dramatic change that occurred during the 20s or the dramatic difference between the 20s and 30s.

Comment: It's `the [A and B]` or `[the A] and [the B]`.  Either way is fine.

Comment: Also, that "distributive property" works with the indefinite article as well, and different conjunctions, too: `an [A or B]` can be also be expressed as `[an A] or [a B]`.

Comment: There are 18 years between the 20's and the 30's from 1922 to 1938.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When words are joined by a conjunction, they often share a common article. As long as they're not interrupted by other words, there's no problem.

It's simply not necessary to write *between the 20s and the 30s*. As long as they agree in number, and are using the same article (i.e. this doesn't work with an a/an combination), it's fine.

In your example, I prefer **not** omitting *the*, but that's a style choice, so follow your own preference here.

Comment: Please, could you give an example where "the" can't be omitted?