# How many "the"s are needed for a branch of superlatives? And what order of them is right?

Tags: definite-article, superlatives, adjective-order

When there are several superlative degree adjectives combined together, should every superlative form has "the", or should only one single "the" is put at the beginning?

For example,

> *the* fastest, *the* cheapest, and *the* most accessible siege aircraft

> *the* fastest, cheapest, and most accessible siege aircraft

which one is correct?

---

By the way, is the order of these adjective (fastest, cheapest, most accessible) right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use article 'the' with conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99590/how-to-use-article-the-with-conjunction) See also [Should "the" be repeated when connected by "and" and "same"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26212/) and [Why is using only one "a" enough in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24758/), among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are technically 'correct'.
It just depends how much sensationalism you are trying to create.

> "The biggest, the best, the most fantastic in the world!
> …introducing…
> … sliced bread!"

Is like a ringmaster or show host introducing an exciting guest, or an advertisement telling you how good their new product is.

> the fastest, cheapest, and most accessible

is simply a list of the properties of the described object.